# Rank Preserving Maps between Metric Spaces

Tags: abstract-algebra, metric-spaces, isometry

Consider two Metric Spaces $(U, d_{U})$ and $(V, d_{V})$.

Here let

$f: U \rightarrow V$

Then $f$ is an isometry between if

$\forall u_{i}, u_{j} \in U$

$d_{U}(u_{i},u_{j}) = d_{V}(f(u_{i}), f(u_{j}))$

I'm interested in studying a different type of mapping in which the ranking of distances between a set element are preserved, i.e.

Let $u_{T}, u_{1}, u_{2}, \dots u_{n} \in U$ and let

$d_{U}(u_{T}, u_{1}) \leq d_{U}(u_{T}, u_{2}) \leq \cdots \leq d_{U}(u_{T}, u_{1})$

Then I'm interested in studying maps between $U$ and $V$ such that this is preserved, i.e.

$g:U \rightarrow W$

$d_{U}(u_{T}, u_{1}) \leq d_{U}(u_{T}, u_{2}) \leq \cdots \leq d_{U}(u_{T}, u_{1}) \rightarrow d_{W}(g(u_{T}), g(u_{1})) \leq d_{W}(g(u_{T}), g(u_{2})) \leq \cdots \leq d_{W}(g(u_{T}), g(u_{1}))$

Is this studied at all? and if so, where should I go to find more information about it?

Comment: Obviously Isometries hold this property but I was curious about object types where the direct equality of the distance measures is relaxed.

Answer (score 0):

The chain of inequalities forces equality to hold because the last term in the inequality is the same as the first. Your condition is equivalent to $f$ being isometric.

Comment: Indeed, but what if it wasn't an isometry? what it it was an isometry for some pairings of elements and not others? 
Are there structures outside of Isometries that can be used to study this type of requirement (i.e. rank preserving).

Comment: I should have defined a new function between $U$ and $V$ for my question - I have updated the original question to reflect that.